# Filling a resultant table with corresponding values (row and column) from another table

Tags: python, pandas

I have this 2 tables below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Um6.png

Is there a library or some built-in function that fills up the second table  matching row and columns from it, with the information on the first one?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [DataFrame.pivot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) for converting the first dataframe to the second dataframe?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line with Nick ODell's suggestion, you can use [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), as long as each combination of date and category is unique (because `df.pivot` does not support aggregation).

Assuming your column names are integers 0, 1, and 2, try:

```
# Arguments: index, columns, values
# fill NaN with 0 to match your expected output
df.pivot(0, 1, 2).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks a lot guys.